# Can I make it so that only certain fields are changeable with a PATCH?

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

I have already made it so that only the object's owner can call a PATCH command on a resource, but I would like this user to only be able to update certain fields within this resource. I can do this by creating another resource and altering the first on the hydrate method, but this is cumbersome. Is there a easier alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can mark them as readonly:

```
email = fields.CharField(attribute='email', readonly=True)
```

I am observing that such fields can't be set but no error is raised by Tastypie when user attempts to change them.